# Volume of a semi-circle function plus constant

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

So I have this function

[image]

Now when I try to rotate it around the *x-axis* between the intervals *[148,160]* 360 degrees, the volume contains imaginary answers i.e.

[image]
Now since we are talking about volume how can it be that when you rotate a function like mine around the *x-axis* 360 degrees, that it turns out to have imaginary constants?

Did I do anything wrong? If so how would I even begin to evaluate the volume of the function around this interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that when $x> 150 + \sqrt{50} $, the value under the square root is negative, hence is complex valued.

Thus, if you're looking at the "rotation of the real-valued graph", you want to restrict to the range $[148, 150 + \sqrt{50} ]$.

---

Note: It is reasonable to ask what is the volume of rotation of the line $y = i$ about the x-axis. So, check for what the problem is asking about.

Comment: So my interval is still too big for x to be considered real?

Comment: Your interval is too big for $ \sqrt{ 50 - (x-150)^2 + 4 $ to be real.